# Customize datePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to show my date picker dialog like this where the background is blurred like a normal datePickerDialog but also has extra components like a textview and button. I cant seem to get this from making the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to custom very much to can create your DatePicker.

I only support a simple DatePicker and you must improve it:

1.Create custom layout: `layoutdatetime.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     >
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textSize="24sp"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:text="SELECT TO DATE" />
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@color/white"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>         <CalendarView  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>             android:id="@+id/calendarView"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>              />
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="right"
>             android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:textColor="#f54242"
>                 android:text="Cancel" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/btnOK"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:textColor="#f54242"
>                 android:text="OK" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button3"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

2. Create funtion display DatePicker and custom process of controls on layout

> ```
> public void ShowDate() {
>         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
>         dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layoutdatetime);
>         dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
>         TextView btnCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
>         btnCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.cancel());
>         dialog.show();
>     }
> ```

Comment: good code. But, OP might also want to get the date right? Why not make a custom dialog class? That will make the code look better and also better

Answer (score 0):

Requirements:
View binding

---

1. Create a custom layout named `layoutdatetime.xml` : (Taken from Dt's answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71749350/17133283).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="SELECT TO DATE" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <CalendarView  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#f54242"
                android:text="Cancel" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnOK"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#f54242"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Make a class named `DateListener` and paste this code:

```java
public interface DateListener {
    void onDateNotPicked();
    void onDatePicked(Date date);

    void onGenerateStatement();
}
```

2. To make use of that, make this class and paste the code:

```java
public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends Dialog {

    private DateListener listener;
    private LayoutdatetimeBinding binding;

    public CustomDatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, DateListener dateListener) {
        super(context);
        listener = dateListener;
        binding = LayoutdatetimeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        binding.btnOK.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            listener.onDatePicked(new Date(binding.calendarView.getDate()));
            dismiss();
        });
        
        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dismiss();
            listener.onDateNotPicked();
        });
        
        binding.generateStatement.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            listener.onGenerateStatement();
            dismiss();
        });
    }
}
```

3. Show it in this way:

```java
CustomDatePickerDialog dialog = new CustomDatePickerDialog(this, new DateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateNotPicked() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "date not picked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDatePicked(Date date) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "date picked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onGenerateStatement() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "statemnt generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
dialog.show();
```